# Why my HLOOKUP Excel formula is not working?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the `HLOOKUP()` formula and I am sure it is looking at the "Development" tab. This is where I could not figure it out (May it's referring to the table name on the "Development" tab). I am getting an error "N/A".

The thing is, I didn't actually create this Excel sheet. I'm just trying to reverse-engineer it.

```
   =1-HLOOKUP(F8,LDF_By_Age,4,FALSE)
```

[image]

Expect answers are.

[image]

[Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G-VrOCGFBQgVlefRuipbK0gXs-7EKKQm/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111724893429014307267&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: By default headers of **`Structured References`** aka **`Tables`** are always `Text`, if numbers or dates(which are essentially numbers) are used needs to be converted to numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, if you are using **`Structured References`** and you have numbers as **`Headers`** then it gets formatted as `Text` and hence why the formula you are using isn't working. It needs to be converted to number.

From my comments above:

> *By default headers of **Structured References** aka **Tables** are always*
> ***Text formatted**, if **numbers** or **dates**(which are **essentially** numbers) are used*
> *needs to be **converted/coerced** to numbers.*

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G8</kbd>

```
=1-HLOOKUP(F8,LDF_By_Age/1,4,FALSE)
```

---

The above formula needs to be filled down!

---

Also, to coerce the text to a number you can also `divide by 1` or `multiply by 1` or `add 0` or use `double unary --`.!

---

One more thing, which I have noticed, you probably need an approximate match, If I am not wrong, then the last param of <kbd>HLOOKUP()</kbd> i.e. **`[range_lookup]`** should be `TRUE` and not `FALSE` then the formula will be :

```
=1-HLOOKUP(F8,LDF_By_Age/1,4,TRUE)
```

---

**Note:** We can also use `0` for `FALSE` and `1` for `TRUE` in the last parameter of <kbd>HLOOKUP()</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much but I am still getting an error, So I have changed the Age on Development tab to a number and used your formula.  I am getting an error "#VALUES!". Am I missing anything? 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZU9XYo6bS95PPvJNwSEV7slkrxOR9ccs/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111724893429014307267&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @bidevkelly are you using `Excel` or `Google-Sheets`?

Comment: I am using MS Excel, the Desktop version

Comment: You can refer this still works on my end. May be you need to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode. As it still works on my end **[here you can see](https://imgur.com/gallery/GVjwImR)** btw I am using `MS365` may be you are not using updated version or may be in older version.

Comment: @bidevkelly is it working now?. Download **[file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckF6UE4P-kRq49UU6?e=J2F0Lo)** to check/verify!

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working on your file but not my file. Now I know the issue, so I will try to debug this. Again, thank you so much